# Android - Dynamically name resources inside code

Tags: android, string, layout, android-intent, resources

Quiet simply, I am trying to reuse my Adapters and Activity classes. When I call the Intent to open my Activity, I pass name of the Layout I want to inflate as a StringExtra like this:

```
i.putExtra("layout_name", "layout_a");
```

Then inside my Activity I obtain the extra:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String layout_name = i.getStringExtra("layout_name");
```

Now I want to use this in this format:

```
setContentView(R.layout. + layout_name);
```

Is something like this possible? What's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass layout identifier:

```
i.putExtra("layout_id", R.layout.your_layout);
```

Get this value as

```
int layout_id = getIntent().getIntExtra("layout_id");
```

Set this id as

```
setContentView(layout_id);
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like,

```
int layoutID = getResources().getIdentifier("layout_name" , "layout", getPackageName());
setContentView(layoutID);
```

Comment: More info Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: I tried this out but no luck, I got error - no Resource Found. I'm sure it's me doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try Int ID of resource and use it.

```
int layout = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("LayoutID");
setContentView(layout);
```

Hope it Helps!!